# MYSQL: Query data between two dates using date_format doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to make a query between two dates. The dates are input as `String` format, [%d/%b/%y](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp), which are gotten from select boxes.

```
SELECT * FROM `Data`
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%d/%b/%Y') 
BETWEEN '25/Feb/2008' AND '04/Mar/2008'
```

I got no result from the query above. However, the following query gave me some results :

```
SELECT * FROM `Data`
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%d/%b/%Y') 
BETWEEN '25/Feb/2008' AND '28/Feb/2008'
```

I thought that the problem occurred because it compared the text instead of `Date` format. I have been searching for an hour. Any help would be very appreciated.

**EDIT:** Finally, I found the solution as following.

```
SELECT * FROM `Data`
WHERE DATE(`Begin`) BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('25/Feb/2008', '%d/%b/%Y') AND 
STR_TO_DATE('04/Feb/2008', '%d/%b/%Y')
```

Comment: This is back to front. Also, you have a STRing which you want TO interpret as a DATE (see what I did there?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `date_format`, you convert a `date` to a `varchar`, meaning all the comparisons you're making on it will be **lexicographical**, instead of date-based. Instead, you should convert your string literals to dates:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   `data`
WHERE  `date` BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('25/Feb/2008', '%d/%y/%m') AND 
                      STR_TO_DATE('28/Feb/2008', '%d/%y/%m')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I got the solution based on your idea.